# Python yield program run

Tags: python, yield

The result of below program is 
`2 step 3 step 5 step 7 step`

How does yield run? What does yield return, by `n` or it's `generator`?
Why isn't number 9's answer the result (`2 step 3 step 5 step 7 step step`)?
Can you explain how the program is run?

```
def _odd_iter():
    n = 1
    while True:
        n = n+2
        yield n

def _not_divisible(n):
    return lambda x:x%n >0

def primes():
    yield 2
    it = _odd_iter()
    while True:
        print('step')
        n = next(it)
        yield n
        it = filter(_not_divisible(n),it)

c = primes()
for i in c:
    if i<10:
        print(i)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: If you want 9 to appear, get rid of the line `it = filter(_not_divisible(n),it)`.  Of course, then you're no longer emitting primes...

Comment: @ivanrres Did my post answer your question? If not, what is still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

What the program is doing is determined by the `for`-loop in the last five lines. The loop is consuming primes (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, ...) produced by the generator `c`.

`c` does not produce 9 because 9 is not a prime (it is divisible by 3).

And the program is not printing 11, 13, ... because the `for`-loop is exited when `i` becomes 11 (11 is not less than 10).